# How to hide react components from unauthorized users in Asp net core app?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I created an Asp net core app with react and authorization. I used `dotnet new react -o <project_name> -au Individual` command for this. There is "FetchData" component in project that looks like this:
[image]
You can't go there by link, if you are not authorized. But i noticed one problem. You can still look at the component in responsed code from server:[image]
So how can i hide this component from unauthorized users?

Comment: Please refer this article to use [AuthorizeRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#protect-a-client-side-route-react) protect the client-side route, and apply the [Authorize] attribute to the endpoint. You could also refer this article to configure the application with Authorization : [Sample Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: @ZhiLv i'm already using AuthrorizeRoute and Authorize attribute. The problem is that an unauthorized user can see the code of the component.

Comment: Hi @olegshmel, in the view page, you could add if condition statement to check whether the user is authorized or not, if unauthorized, don't render the content.

Comment: @ZhiLv I do so, but in theory, an unauthorized user can reproduce the component using the component code, even if it is not rendered

Comment: Hi @olegshmel, can you share the relates code and tell us the detail steps to reproduce the problem?  And what do you mean about "an unauthorized user can reproduce the component using the component code, even if it is not rendered", I tried to create a sample using the react template, it seems that in the FetchData component, when calling the api to get the data, it should set the Authorization header, for the unauthorized user, it will redirect to the login page. So, can you explain more detail about that?

Comment: @ZhiLv thanks for supporting! I created an asp net core application using the react template. To understand my problem, follow these steps: 1) Go to the site without logging in and open the developer tools. 2) Go to the "Networks" tab and in the search (ctrl + f) enter class FetchData. Here it is possible to view the component code, which I want to prevent (only for unauthorized users, of course). Also, the user can simply intercept the request and remove the condition responsible for checking whether the user is authorized or not.

Comment: Hi @olegshmel, as we all known, when we build the react application, it will generate some chunks.js file which will contain the component's js file content, so you can see the FetchData.js content no matter user login or not. But even the user can see the js file content, the unauthorized user still has no permission to access the real data. Why you want to limit unauthorized user to see the FetchData.js content, does it have any sensitive information? If the js file contains the sensitive information, perhaps you could consider adding the js script dynamic.

Comment: @ZhiLv I do not like the concept itself that even those components are transferred that an ordinary user will definitely not need. As for the fact that they still will not get access to the api for authorized users, I know. Can you explain how I can do dynamic loading of scripts and use it all with react-router?

Comment: @ZhiLv are you still here?